# What is the significance of the Grand Inquisitor in The Brothers Karamazov?

Tags: symbolism, russian-language, fyodor-dostoyevsky, the-brothers-karamazov

In *The Brothers Karamazov*, Ivan tells a long story to Alyosha about the Grand Inquisitor. I have been trying to grasp its meaning for some time, but what is the significance of that story?

Comment: Russian wikipedia entry offers very good overview: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) I think it could be possible to understand with machine traslation